# Array reduce on javascript return wrong values with array chainability

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get some math on an array of objects. Using the map for getting the value inside of the object and then reduce for made the calcules. For some reason reduce not return the correct value.

This is an example:

```
var test = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 2
}];
var newe = test.map((x) => x.value).reduce(function(total, sum) {
  console.log([total, sum]);
  return total + (sum * 2);
});
```

It's supposed to return 4, however, it returns 2.

Do you have an idea what is wrong? I share the code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dleo7/ckgnrubh/10/

Comment: You forgot to give the `reduce` an initial value, so it doesn't iterate at all and only resolves to the value of the one `value`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ckgnrubh/11/

Comment: Always pass an initial value to reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doc from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description)
>
> If `initialValue` isn't provided, `reduce()` will execute the callback function starting at index `1`, skipping the first index. If `initialValue` is provided, it will start at index `0`.

So, basically, your approach is skipping the first index `0` and the first value is returned `2`.  To solve this, you need to pass the `initialValue`, in this case, `0`.

```js
var test = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 2
}];
var newe = test.map((x) => x.value).reduce(function(total, sum) {
  return total + (sum * 2);
}, 0);
// ^
// |
// +---- InitialValue

console.log(newe);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass initial value to reduce function,

```
var test = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 2
}];
var newe = test.map((x) => x.value).reduce(function(total, sum) {
  console.log([total, sum]);
  return total + (sum * 2);
}, 0);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = newe;
```